# couldn't verify android inapp billing via php server

Tags: android, in-app-billing, verify

I need to verify android purchase data via php server but the verification alway return false.
Here my android code in case purchase success:

```
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    //TODO send purchase info to web server, should verify bill info
    String postData = "purchase_data=" + purchase.getOriginalJson() + "&"
                    + "signature=" + purchase.getSignature();
    webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
}
```

and here is my php code:

```
$receipt = $_POST['purchase_data'];
$billInfo = json_decode($receipt,true);
$signature = $_POST['signature'];
$public_key_base64 = "my base64 public key";
$key =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".
        chunk_split($public_key_base64, 64,"\n").
       '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';   

$key = openssl_get_publickey($key);

$signature = base64_decode($signature);

$result = openssl_verify($billInfo, $signature, $key);
if (0 === $result) {
        return false;
    } else if (1 !== $result) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

the returned value is always false. Who can tell me where my wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: i found that `purchase.getSignature();` value is difference for each transaction. So what is correct signature i should obtain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what you mistaked.

```
$receipt = $_POST['purchase_data'];
$billInfo = json_decode($receipt,true);
...
$result = openssl_verify($billInfo, $signature, $key);
```

you verified decoded object with key. so it is always be failed.

try this and get success,

```
$result = openssl_verify($receipt, $signature, $key);
```

signature verify string(purchase_data) not decoded OBJECT.